# Relation with one content type to other

Tags: nodes

How can I give relation once content type to other. Eg If I have a product and the product sub items. I need to make a product content and a product_sub_item content type. Also need to select the product while creating the sub item. How to achieve this relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using node_references cck module we can achive this. In manage fields need to create a new field and select the type node reference and the parent type to be referenced

Comment: When you ask a question, you should specify whether you mean Drupal 6 or Drupal 7.  This answer is for Drupal 6; the other answers above all presumed Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the module "[References](http://drupal.org/project/references)". It allows you to create a field where you can reference on other content types and nodes.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you might also want to take a look at the module [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) which looks to have a brighter future in terms of active maintenance and integration with other Drupal contribs. Another module that will come handy is [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules).

For both modules there are good introductory screencasts available by Johan Falk on http://dev.nodeone.se/sv

Answer (score 1):

I discuss some of the different options available here: http://drupal.org/node/1293792#comment-5275780

This discussion is particularly relevant if you care about back-references.  For your use case, perhaps references & cnr would give the best user experience.